# get design attribute value on same page to another component in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, design-attributes

here is design atrribute @api parentcls and childcls i m trying to fetch these design attribute in another component on same page  i tried constructor too but didnt get value on load

```
@api parentcls='';
@api childcls='';

connectedCallback(){
    console.log('connectedcallback',this.parentcls); //value getting
    console.log('connectedcallback',this.childcls); //value getting 
    fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'parentclass', this.parentcls);
    fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'childclass', this.childcls);
}
```

in another component  of same page

```
connectedCallback() {
    registerListener('parentclass', this.parentcss, this);
    registerListener('childclass', this.childcss, this);
}
```

Comment: can you show what is fireEvent?

Comment: `import {fireEvent} from 'c/pubsub';`     event from main component to send  values @salesforce-sas

Comment: Can you show full code? there are multiple steps involved in using pubsub, so will be able to help better if I acn see full flow